# Copying stored procedures and changing database reference

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, copy

I have a stored procedure that copies all the stored procedures in one database to another, changing the database reference.  However, it currently has to be run on the destination db, whereas I would prefer to run it on the source db.  I'm unsure how to point the relevant statement to the correct db.

```
-- Delete all procedures in TO database - must run on TO db
DECLARE @procName varchar(500)
DECLARE cur1 cursor FOR 
    SELECT [name] FROM [DestDB].sys.objects WHERE type = 'p'
OPEN cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @procName
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC('drop procedure [' + @procName + ']')  --Problem statement
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @procName
END
CLOSE cur1
DEALLOCATE cur1

-- Copy all procedures from FROM database
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(32) = 'DestDB'; --TO database
DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT Definition
   FROM [SourceDB].[sys].[procedures] p
   INNER JOIN [SourceDB].sys.sql_modules m ON p.object_id = m.object_id
OPEN cur2
FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @sql
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
   SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'''','''''')
   SET @sql = 'USE [' + @Name + ']; EXEC(''' + @sql + ''')'
   EXEC(@sql)
   FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @sql
END             
CLOSE cur2
DEALLOCATE cur2
```

The problem is the 'drop procedure ' call.  You can't specify the database in the call, so it operates on the active one.  I need to be able to specify the database that the 'drop procedure' runs on, so I can run the procedure from the source db.

Comment: An easier way would be to script out the procs from the source database as `"CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE ...."`, so if the proc already exists in the target database it gets update else it will just simply get created. There is already native support for these actions, why try to invent the wheel?

Comment: Thanks.  I considered that, but some of our supported sql server instances predate 'CREATE OR ALTER'.

Comment: Then you need to consider upgrading to a newer version. Not just for the `create or alter` functionality but because that feature was introduced in sql server 2016 sp1. Anything older means it is completely out of support and needs to be upgraded.

Comment: True, true, but we have customers on SQL Server 2014 and we can't dictate what SQL Server version they use.

Comment: You can have minimum system requirements. Pick a date and let them know that if they want to have support for the application they need to upgrade to a supported version of sql server by that date. Honestly it is a bad business practice for you to support an application that is running an unsupported version of the database. It not only subjects you to things you can't fix it handcuffs you from improving the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not use a 'USE' statement before the drop, as you are doing later inside the CURSOR?

```
EXEC('USE [' + @Name + ']; drop procedure [' + @procName + ']')
```

Simply DECLARE the @Name variable earlier.
It should work assuming all the procs are in the same database.
"CREATE OR ALTER" should also complete the task, as mentioned, if you're using SQL Server 2016 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `EXEC (<SQL>)` syntax, which is advised against, use `sys.sp_executesql`. YOu could then either you could prefix with the procedure with relevant database, such as `TestDB.sys.sp_executesql`, or you could assign the procedure name to a variable, `SET @ProcName = N'TestDB.sys.sp_executesql'` and then use `EXEC @ProcName`.

When you execute a procedure, it runs in the context of that database, so `DROP PROC YourProc` would drop a procedure in the procedure in the *other* database.

Note that in the below, you get different database IDs:

```sql
USE master;
GO

SELECT DB_ID();

EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT DB_ID();';

DECLARE @ProcName nvarchar(500) = N'model.sys.sp_executesql';
EXEC @ProcName N'SELECT DB_ID();';
```

So, `DROP`ing a procedure would loom like this:

```sql
USE Sandbox; --Connect to a different database
GO
--Create sample proc
CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc1 AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS I;
END;
GO
--Create another sample proc
CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc2 AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1 AS I;
END;
GO
--Switch database
USE master;
GO
EXEC Sandbox.dbo.YourProc1; --Check it works
EXEC Sandbox.dbo.YourProc2; --Check it works
GO
EXEC Sandbox.sys.sp_executesql N'DROP PROC dbo.YourProc1;'; --Drop using 3 part naming
GO
DECLARE @ProcName nvarchar(500) = N'Sandbox.sys.sp_executesql';
EXEC @ProcName N'DROP PROC dbo.YourProc2;'; --Drop using variable
GO
EXEC Sandbox.dbo.YourProc1; --Fails
GO
EXEC Sandbox.dbo.YourProc2; --Fails
```

Comment: Thank you.  Useful to know, but I'm not trying to run a stored procedure on the destination system from the source system.  I wish to run the stored procedure on the source system, but execute the 'drop procedure' statement on the destination system.

Comment: What do you mean by "system"? The above will run the dynamic code in the other *database*. Do you actually have multiple servers involved or something? That isn't clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is what I wound up with:

```
    USE [DestDB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[USP_Update_1_DropAndCopy_Procs]    Script Date: 10/9/2023 10:58:25 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    -- =================================================================================
    -- Author:      Me
    -- Description: Copy stored procedures from source to destination
    -- Create date: 10/06/2023
    -- =================================================================================
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_Update_1_DropAndCopy_Procs] 
        @SourceServer varchar(50),
        @SourceDB varchar(50),
        @DestDB varchar(50)
    AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

        -- Delete all procedures in DESTINATION database
        DECLARE @procName varchar(500)EXEC('DECLARE cur1 cursor FOR SELECT [name] FROM [' + @DestDB + '].[sys].[objects] WHERE type = ''p'' ')
        OPEN cur1
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @procName
        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC('USE [' + @DestDB + ']; drop procedure [' + @procName + ']')
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 INTO @procName
        END
        CLOSE cur1
        DEALLOCATE cur1

        -- Copy all procedures from SOURCE database
        EXEC('DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT Definition FROM [' + @SourceServer + '].[' + @SourceDB + '].[sys].[procedures] p INNER JOIN [' + @SourceServer + '].[' + @SourceDB + '].sys.sql_modules m ON p.object_id = m.object_id')
        OPEN cur2
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @sql
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN   
            SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql,'''','''''')   
            SET @sql = 'USE [' + @DestDB + ']; EXEC(''' + @sql + ''')'   
            EXEC(@sql)   
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur2 INTO @sql
        END             
        CLOSE cur2
        DEALLOCATE cur2

    END
```